# Making one global cookie-list from face-remap-add-relative

Tags: org-mode, faces

What would be an neat strategy that accumulate cookies from `face-remap-add-relative` in a list ?

```
(defun komis-luna-hglevel-tfcadd ()
  "Set foreground colours of headings according to level.
The function 'face-remap-add-relative' uses a cookie to identify
and remove the remapping later with 'face-remap-remove-relative'."

  (setq cookie-level-1
     (face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-1
                              '(:foreground "cyan1")))

  (setq cookie-level-2
     (face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-2
                             '(:foreground "chartreuse")))

  (setq cookie-level-3
    (face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-3
                             '(:foreground "dark orange"))) )
```

Later, I remove the remapping with face-remap-remove-relative as follows.

```
(defun komis-luna-hglevel-tfcrmv ()
  "Remove the typeface previously added for org-level-N faces."

  (face-remap-remove-relative cookie-level-1)
  (face-remap-remove-relative cookie-level-2)
  (face-remap-remove-relative cookie-level-3))
```

It has been suggested to make a list `cookie-list` and push the cookies onto it.  Later applying a do-list over the cookies calling `face-remap-remove-relative` on each to remove them. Thus only one global.

Although something looking like would work, I still have to make all the 'cookie-level-N' variables nevertheless.

```
;; Accumulate the cookies in a list
(setq cookie-list (list cookie-level-1 cookie-level-2 cookie-level-3)))
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: A question about how to accumulate the cookies.  The solution still has to make each cookie though and then fill the list.  OR one can just use a `push` upon the function into a single global cookie list `cookie-list`.

Comment: Please post the question explicitly in the question, and get rid of anything that's extraneous. Is the question about the advantages of separate variables or a single list-valued variable? If so, be specific about what kind of comparison you're looking for. Is the question only about how to add items to a list? It's not clear (to me) what you're asking (or why).

Comment: `(push (face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-1 '(:foreground "cyan1")) cookie-list)`

Comment: @Drew Shall update as instructed.  Fran Much appreciate your illustration.

Comment: Note that this question has nothing to do with Emacs: it is a basic question on Lisp usage, which is best answered by whatever introductory Lisp textbook you can get your hands on.